# Problems with Eclipse, can't import org.apache.maven.surefire.report.RunListener;

Tags: java, eclipse, testng

I'm writing a TestNG Provider for a Testframework. In that way I must import the RunListener Interface (org.apache.maven.surefire.report.RunListener) to Eclipse. But Eclipse tells me that the Import cannot be resolved. I have no Idea what's the problem is and I hope that you can tell me a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Usually projects (like TestNG) depend on other projects. In your case you need to download the SureFire-Project (maybe some other projects too).

If eclipse says "can not be resolved", there are nearly always missing .jar-files.

Find and add your .jar-file to the "Java Build Path libraries" of your project. This will resolve your dependency issue.

(Maven can "download, find and add" those .jar-files automatically)